# Show available Physical memory on Device (iphone/ipad)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Anybody knows how to find out how much physical memory is used and available now?

I need to show in my iPad application smth like this:

Free memory is 14.1 / 16Gb
You application's files takes 1412 Mb

I will store big files in my app and should know about used memory - 
to delete some files and write new

smth like physical memory managment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like by "memory" you mean filesystem storage. Something like this should get you what you want:

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *info = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:path error:NULL];
NSUInteger totalSpace = [[info objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize] unsignedIntegerValue];
NSUInteger freeSpace = [[info objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] unsignedIntegerValue];
```